# Generate signature with querystring containing spaces in OAuth 1.0

Tags: oauth, urlencode

I am trying to create a signature for OAuth 1 to access a website.  One of the endpoints has a query string that takes the form of a simple SQL statement such as:

?query=select * from customer

I know - horrible.

Anyways, my signature works fine for all other calls until I try to use a statement that has a space in the query string parameter value.  I have tried a number of ways to UrlEncode the query string, but I always get the same result - a 401:

query%3Dselect%20%2A%20from%20term
query%3Dselect+%2A+from+term

I also tried this OAuth signature checker: http://quonos.nl/oauthTester/ but all it tells me is that "select * from term" is bad - not much help.

Does anyone know what format this querystring should be in for the base string?

Comment: Hi, I know I'm asking this more than a year late, but did you find a solution to your issue? I'm running into the same issue now when using OAuth 1.0, with one of my query parameters having a space in between.

Comment: I think there was an eventual workaround, but I do not remember what it is and I no longer have access to that code base.  If I remember correctly, this was a problem surrounding the Quickbooks Online Api.  Sorry I can't be of more help!